# How to encode multi-label representation using index?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I want to encode `[[1, 2], [4]]` to

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

while `sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelbinarizer` only gives

```
[[1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1]]
```

Anyone knows how to do it using `Numpy` or `Pandas` or `sklearn` built-in function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MultilabelBinarizer will only know what you send in it. When it sees only 3 distinct classes, it will assign 3 columns only.

You need to set the `classes` param to set the total number of classes you are expecting in your dataset (in the order you want in the columns):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=[0,1,2,3,4])
mlb.fit_transform([[1, 2], [4]])

#Output
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Could LabelBinarizer do this?

Comment: @danche No. LabelBinarizer only works on single list. Not list of lists.